# Issue with BACS place order Internal Server Error in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem in Checkout page: when I click Place Order and select BACS as payment method. Every time shows to me an Internal Server Error.

This error only happen when I select BACS, the others payment methods works fine.

Additional, the order has placed, but to the client receive this message, and delete the product list. Any Ideas? Thanks

[Error in Checkout Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKO75.png)

Comment: Have a look at your error logs, test in dev, basic debugging etc etc. There's nothing we can do with this.

Comment: Do you have any plugins listed in plugin directory which ate connected to checkout or payment gateway?

Comment: And how I can get error logs? Sorry for the question

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Comment: Did u get error log?

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_payment_method() on null in /home/wp_pmhxre/cuatrimotos.cl/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php:249

That is the error

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was an error in the Admin/User emails, they have an error and shows to me the error, I replaced these files with original files from a clean version of WooCommerce and works fine. Thanks for the idea of search the error_log files. Thanks!